# Is deciding if a ring is a UFD always possible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is deciding if a ring is a UFD always possible ?

Is there a simple proof of that ?

Comment: This makes no sense as it stands. A ring is an infinitary object; it can't be the input to a decision problem. You need to fix a specific way of describing rings with finite strings before you can ask about decidability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A ring is always either a UFD or not.

How easily it is to *determine* whether it is or not depends entirely on which *definition* of the ring we have available. For example, consider the ring structure on $\mathbb Z^2$ defined by

$$ \langle a,b\rangle + \langle c,d\rangle = \langle a+c, b+d\rangle $$

$$ \langle a,b \rangle \times \langle c,d\rangle = \begin{cases}
  \langle ac-bd, bc+ad\rangle & \text{if the Riemann hypothesis is true} \\
  \langle ac-5bd, bc+ad \rangle & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

This ring is either isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[i]$ (which is UFD) or to $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ (which is not), but it is extremely difficult to determine which of these is the case.

There are families of definitions of rings where it is *provably impossible* for any procedure to correctly determine whether each of them defines a UFD. (In the above construction, replace "the Riemann hypothesis is true" with "Turing machine $n$ halts on the empty tape").

Comment: I think that $(\mathbb{Z},+_R,\times_R)$ is always a UFD. whether the riemann hypothesis is true or not

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[{\sqrt{-5}}]$ is not a UFD

Comment: No its just my fault. At the beginning I thought that $f$ is a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}$ and itself, thus $(\mathbb{Z},+_R,\times_R)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, hence a UFD

Comment: Now I understand +1

Comment: @Amr: I can see it was confusing. I've switched the example for one that doesn't invite that misunderstanding.

Comment: Its OK both are clear. As I said, it was my fault

Comment: Im sorry but I disagree. I mean you defined 2 rings instead of one and defined to pick which one depending on the Riemann Hypothesis !
In other words you did not define a ring consistantly and unconditionally.

Comment: Although you have a point that adding the word "given" would have been better.

Comment: @mick: No, there's only one ring defined. It has one definition that applies without exception, always. Somewhere inside the definition of its multiplication operator is an expression that's hard to reason about. That doesn't make it two rings.

Comment: What about if I add 'given' ?

Comment: or with given norm ?

Comment: Unique factorization does not depend on any norm. And the point is exactly that the hardness deciding whether a ring is UFD depends intrinsically on **how that ring is given** to you.